# CSS Change color based on attribute of closest class

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

This process has been driving me nuts.  I am trying to make foundations abide system look nicer.  I have created a system that replaces the error class with a success and error system.  Everything works well except I am having an issue displaying the success once the field is checked.

HTML

```
<form data-abide="ajax" id="addNewUser" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div>
        <label class="label" for="fname"><span class="requiredRed">*</span> First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required="" value="Douglas" aria-invalid="false">
        <div class="fa fa-info-circle errspan fail" style=""><div><p>You must enter a First Name</p></div></div>
        <div class="fa fa-check-circle errspan success"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have been trying to find if there is a easy way through css to display success based on the 'aria-invalid' attribute such as.

```
[data-abide] input[aria-invalid='false'] + div.success{ display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue.  I was missing a + div

```
[data-abide] input[aria-invalid='false'] + div + div.success{ display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to figure out what you mean. If some JavaScript handler is triggered only once, but no longer afterwards, the handler often needs to be reattached. For example if there is a button in an ajax panel the click event handler must be added to the button any time the panel is reloaded. Is it such a kind of problem?